# Calling C# function from AngularJs script in Xamarin Forms PCL Universal Windows Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, hybrid, xamarin.uwp

I am developing a cross platform xamarin forms application. I have created a Portable Cross-Platform App, in which I am trying to open local HTML pages in webview. For calling C# function from Angularjs, I have implemented hybrid web view concepts.

My Angularjs Function

```
 $scope.SyncServerJobs = function () {
    //$scope.loadActList();
   window.CommInterface.syncServerJobs("");
}
```

In My Universal Windows Project

```
 public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView>
{
    public CommInterface communicator = new CommInterface();

    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.external.notify(data);}";
    const string SyncServerJobs = "function syncServerJobs(data){window.external.notify(data);}";

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new WebView();
            webView.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.NavigationStarting -= OnWebViewNavigationStarted;
            Control.NavigationCompleted -= OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
            Control.ScriptNotify -= OnWebViewScriptNotify;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.NavigationStarting += OnWebViewNavigationStarted;
            Control.NavigationCompleted += OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
            Control.ScriptNotify += OnWebViewScriptNotify;
            Control.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Content//{0}", Element.Uri));
        }
    }

    private void OnWebViewNavigationStarted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Control != null && Element != null)
        {
            communicator = new CommInterface();
            Control.AddWebAllowedObject("CommInterface", communicator);
        }
    }

    async void OnWebViewNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSuccess)
        {
            // Inject JS script
            await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { JavaScriptFunction });
            await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { SyncServerJobs });
        }
    }

    void OnWebViewScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction(e.Value);
    }
}
```

My commInterface class

```
 [AllowForWeb]
public sealed class CommInterface
{
    readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public CommInterface()
    {

    }

    public void syncServerJobs(string data)
    {
        HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;
        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
        {
            hybridRenderer.Element.SyncServerJobs(data);
        }
    }
}
```

As like in Android project I am using CommInterface class to communicate with database class in Portable library. But in my Universal Windows project, I am not able to communicate with Csharp functions to run CSharp CRUD functions. How can I call the CSharp function from script?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to communicate with Csharp functions to run CSharp CRUD functions. How can I call the CSharp function from script?

You have injected `JS` script after webView navigation Completed. In another words the `await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { JavaScriptFunction });` was declared in `JS` scope.

Scripts in the web view content can use [**window.external.notify**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view) with a string parameter to send information back to your app. To receive these messages, handle the [`ScriptNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ScriptNotify) event.

So The `ScriptNotify` event would be triggered when you executed the `JavaScriptFunction` in `JS` scope like the follwing code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:invokeCSCode($('#name').val());">Invoke C# Code</button>
<br/>
<p id="result">Result:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function log(str)
{
    $('#result').text($('#result').text() + " " + str);
}

function invokeCSCode(data) {
    try {
        log("Sending Data:" + data);
        invokeCSharpAction(data);    
    }
    catch (err){
        log(err);
    }
}
```

I found you have handled the `ScriptNotify` event by excuted `Element.InvokeAction(e.Value);` So I infer that you declared the `InvokeAction` for hybrid web view.

```
public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
{
    action = callback;
}

public void Cleanup()
{
    action = null;
}

public void InvokeAction(string data)
{
    if (action == null || data == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    action.Invoke(data);
}
```

And then you could process CSharp CRUD functions in the callback function like the following code.

```
smbridwebview.RegisterAction(data => {
// process CSharp CRUD functions 
});
```